# EF Code First - How to Deploy to Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, azure-web-app-service

I've been struggling with this all day.

I can't make my WebApi to access my database.
I'm using the Code First approach with Entity Framework.

When I'm deploying, a new connection string is added to web.config.
And this raises an exception:

This is what I've got in my web.config (locally):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ArquitecturaNativaDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ArquitecturaNativaDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And this is what I do when I'm deploying:
[image]
Obviously, there's the connection string that should be used when deployed.

I used to think that when the app is being deployed my web.config is modified and my connection string used locally would be replaced for that one there in the textbox of the image.

But no, instead, I got this in my server:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ArquitecturaNativaDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ArquitecturaNativaDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ArquitecturaNativaDB_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=mydbserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What's that `ArquitecturaNativaDB_DatabasePublish` doing there?
I believe this is the root of my problem, because when I make a request I get an exception response:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
```

This is the constructor of my DbContext:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("name=ArquitecturaNativaDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }
```

I'm so tired of trying to solve this issue.
Any hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use web.config transform instead of using web deploy settings.

[Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="ReleaseSQLServer" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It's more workaround than fix, but it should  work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make absolutely sure that the connection string you want is the one being used, specify the connection string on your Web App's App's Application Settings blade in the Azure Portal. Scroll down to the Connection Strings section, and specify your connection string there. What's specified here takes precedence over anything in your web.config file. Going this route also means that if you do publish the wrong configuration (using the debug config as opposed to the release config or whatever other configuration you've defined for your web.config transform), you will still use the correct connection string.